# POSTGRESQL looping inside SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good day!

Suppose I have these 2 tables:

```
Table A
+----+--------+
| ID | RLIMIT |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 4      |
+----+--------+

Table B
+----+-----+-------+
| ID | AID | UBURN |
+----+-----+-------+
| 1  | 1   | 1     |
+----+-----+-------+
| 2  | 1   | 1     |
+----+-----+-------+
| 3  | 1   | 2     |
+----+-----+-------+
| 4  | 1   | 3     |
+----+-----+-------+
| 5  | 1   | 3     |
+----+-----+-------+
```

I wanted to count how many 1s, 2s, 3s, and 4s are there in Table B and RLIMIT in Table A as my loop indicator. This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| TALLY 1 | TALLY 2 | TALLY 3 | TALLY 4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2       | 1       | 2       | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

So far this is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
BEGIN
  FOR counter IN 0 .. a.RLIMIT
  LOOP
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE b.UBURN = counter+1) AS "TALLY counter"
  END LOOP
END
FROM tableB b
INNER JOIN tableA a ON b.AID = a.ID;
```

Unfortunately, I am encountering a syntax error. Can you shed some light on how can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like a XY problem.  Yes, there are syntax errors in your function (it's missing a select and from, for starters), but I think you should edit your question and describe what you are trying to achieve.  It is very rare to need to use a loop in a pl/pgsql function.  Beginners to sql are often drawn to loops, but it is almost always the wrong approach.

Comment: I don't understand why you need table_a (and the `rlimit`): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3c02c7aa31b74a24322bc44a0dabce0e

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the RLIMIT may change is not constant. It is the "limit" in which I need to tally the UBURN. So let's say the RLIMIT changes to 5, then the output should have TALLY 5 as well. Did I make it clear or just worse?